# I'm trying to write a conditional statement that will check the title of my page to see if certain words are found

Tags: javascript, jquery

All of my pages have this `#splash` ID; I want to swap out the background image of this ID using a class. The best way I can think of is to find key words in the `<title></title>` tags that will tell me which class to add to my ID.

```
if($("header:title").contains("frequently")){
     $("#splash").addClass('splashfaq');
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
yourtitle = $(document).find("title").text();
if(yourtitle.indexOf("frequently")>=0){
    $("#splash").addClass('splashfaq');
}
```

Comment: I tried pasting in this code and no luck. The word "frequently" is a word that the title contains, it's not the only one. Would this code still help me in obtaining my goal?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: It works, but you did some mistakes. First of all, the Fiddle already had a title "jsFiddle Demo". Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/720o2bq3/3/

Comment: Your right. It does work, unfortunately on my site it's not actually doing what I am trying to do. Must be something in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `indexOf`

```
if($('title').text().indexOf('frequently') > -1 ){
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Upd: added fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7tv097u/1/)

Comment: Good.luck, would this find the word "frequently" in my 'title' tag in the 'head' element?

Comment: @cm8188 yep, added fiddle

Comment: I tried creating a sample using your fiddle and it doesn't seem to add the Class

Comment: Judging by your original suggestion it seems that this does work and I may have something in my code that is not allowing the class to be added to my ID @Good.luck thanks for all your help in this matter

Comment: @cm8188 opened your fiddle, got alert "it worked" UPD: found why it was not working with bg-color. It was cause of conflict between bgcolor in #box and .boxRed, adding !important to css rule fixed the problem, for some reason your class rule was placed before id rule in cascade , so it caused the conflict, so here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f8y85424/1/

Comment: many thanks I see exactly what you are saying. I'm going to try this now on my actual project to see if I can get it to function properly.